# How to control the width of columns in Case list in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I'd like to make the width of a column in a case list wide enough to make the column header appear on one line. This column has icons in it, is there anyway to control the width of the column via multimedia size or by some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to control the width of the column in the case list in CommCare.